# How to stop JavaScript File Object from being parsed into raw data by the NextJS API

Tags: javascript, next.js, openai-api, openai-whisper

I am getting an audio file from the user and feeding it through to the OpenAI Whisper API to return the transcription of the audio. This works fine.

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("file", Javascript File Object Goes Here);
data.append("model", "whisper-1");
data.append("language", "en");

const transcription = await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions", {
   headers: {
     Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY}}`,
   },
   method: "POST",
   body: data,
});
```

However, to disguise my API key, I added the above code to the NextJS API endpoint `api/transcribe` and call it from the following piece of code

```
const res = await fetch("api/transcribe", {
   method: "POST",
   body: Javascript File Object Goes Here,
});
```

This doesn't work and get's the following error

```
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: null,
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: true,
    requestIncludesCredentials: true,
    type: 'default',
    status: 400,
    timingInfo: {
      startTime: 2930193.4380999804,
      redirectStartTime: 0,
      redirectEndTime: 0,
      postRedirectStartTime: 2930193.4380999804,
      finalServiceWorkerStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkResponseStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkRequestStartTime: 0,
      endTime: 0,
      encodedBodySize: 223,
      decodedBodySize: 223,
      finalConnectionTimingInfo: null
    },
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [ [URL] ],
    body: { stream: undefined }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(9) {
      'date' => 'Sat, 11 Mar 2023 07:00:43 GMT',
      'content-type' => 'application/json',
      'content-length' => '223',
      'connection' => 'keep-alive',
      'openai-organization' => 'user-62k83f0uipvo3gziejoo9nmm',
      'openai-processing-ms' => '194',
      'openai-version' => '2020-10-01',
      'strict-transport-security' => 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains',
      'x-request-id' => '708585d2ea17964bc733a491eb41439f'
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
```

After inspection it seems the Javascript File Object which is now `req.body` was converted into this, which may or may not be the problem

```
��D�\x00\x12\x10.\x00\x00\x18�\x00p�\x00\x02\x01���\x10>\x1F\x10\x1C\x108N�\x01�����\x04<���b\x19`>\x7F\f\t���9���� 9\f\t�>�\x00~'�B\x0Fˇ�\x17yp�E�\x108\x0F�\x0F��9�\x04�G*$��S��D�\n" +
        '\x118B\x14\x000�$؁*E�t�gC.RBzV\\��\x03�P��U�M4q�I)Ie�\r3�\n' +
        '���m�P��\x18��9p�\x05�:\x10 ְ$�\x10\x01/M݀\x03�� �\'G\x10 �,/}� \x019��D�\x18\x12Y*4\x00\x18�p��8�\x15
�\x18��#����\x1CT�X\x00\x16\x13�h�����r�E���l�)IƔ\'z9\x07\x04a\x13`2\x15�yؖ%��� �]\x03���,EͯHy���$\x10\x03�\x10
h��\x1D��D�!\x18)�|\x01L@\x00���\x07\x06��s\x14X�Dt\x17[⋴KD�8�\x17\x7F������w�2�\x13\'��CR //�ɗ|����+�\x07��\x10~#4\x0F����=f\x02�Do�\r0�(����\f���D�\x13\x16�*�\x01�P\x00&\x14�\f+\x16�i9\x19��b\x1F,z\x14.B@4SZ���́�1K�\'1��
d��������=\\���\t\x11���������s\'��Fc\x19� �U��K\x14���q�\b���D�\x0B\x12�*�\x01�8\x00ej�m��TCg��\x05��\t�?�\x1Ez�\x1C� ��\x05A�d��Ķ���SH݉�M�\x7Fԡ��0�����������8����5...
```

I have tried to stop the parsing of the input file using

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
}
```

but this doesn't work either and simply says that `req.body` is `undefined`

I am new to API Endpoints in NextJS so any help would be useful.

If the original input file would be useful it is at [this page](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T-uqE5Zs5kyvls50-DcSQ2hRnDKTxE0k/view?usp=sharing) and collected using an `<input type="file" accept="audio/*" onChange={saveFile} />` and saves it using `const file = e.target.files[0];`